# Three-month freeze on domain transfers?

Tags: networking, web-development, domains, domain-registrar, godaddy

I am planning on hosting a web app on Google App Engine. I am planning on buying the domain from GoDaddy. Will I have to wait 3 months before I can transfer the domain from GoDaddy to GAE (or at least change the DNS settings to point to the GAE severs)?

Comment: oh boy, here we go. migrated to webmasters. i give it 20 minutes before its closed by a moderator without any downvotes by any other community members..

Comment: Could you edit this down to *only* the details important to the question? All the backstory is obfuscating the issue and basically irrelevant to things *right now* as far as I can tell. For one, in the first case you bought the domain with plans to transfer to another registrar. It sounds like right now, you're buying the domain and hosting elsewhere, with no transfer involved. Yes? Those are different situations, and Verio would have nothing to do with the *current* question.

Comment: @Su' - did the best I could

Answer (score 2):

Most domain registrars require you to wait a specified period of time between transfers (usually 60-90 days) for various reasons, including fraud. I don't know about GoDaddy in terms of whether they will allow you to trasnfer the DNS, but [Namecheap](http://namecheap.com) will get your domain registered for you and allow you to transfer the DNS right away (you still have to wait the 60 days before you can transfer the domain to a different registrar though.)

Answer (score 2):

From the [GoDaddy Support Docs](http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/3560/transferring-domain-names-to-another-registrar):

> NOTE: A 60-day transfer restriction period applies when you register
>   or transfer a domain name, update the registrant contact's
>   organization, or update the registrant contact's first or last name
>   and an organization is not listed. For more information, see ICANN's
>   [Policy on Transfer of Registrations Between
>   Registrars](http://www.icann.org/en/transfers/policy-12jul04.htm) and
>   our [Domain Name Change of Registrant
>   Agreement](http://www.godaddy.com/agreements/showdoc.aspx?pageid=DOMAIN_NC&prog_id=GoDaddy).

So, there you have it, there is a 60-day restriction. But they are simply enforcing the rules set by ICANN.

> (or at least change the DNS settings to point to the GAE severs)

However, I can't believe there is any such restriction (with any registrar) on simply changing the DNS. Some registrars might charge you for this service, but I don't believe GoDaddy does since you can do this yourself via the control panel. Changing the DNS is usually the first thing you want to do after registering a domain, so it would be insane to pose a time restriction on this.